# Cliches to avoid when developing a fantasy nomad culture

Tags: nomads

The hero of a fantasy or science fiction story goes to another world and meets a fictional group of semi-nomadic and/or hunter-gatherer people, but, like, maybe not in a transparently racist way.

1. They don't need a white hero (or if they're aliens, a human hero) to step in and save them from something they really could have saved themselves from without him.
2. They don't have a village with a totem pole and teepees.
3. They don't have a witch doctor or fortune teller who curses people.
4. The hero can't learn all their ways in a month and somehow become the best at them. The nomads have been doing this stuff their whole lives and have normal human intelligence, therefore they are experts at what they do.
5. If they don't read, they must have a sophisticated system for passing on knowledge through apprenticeship, song, oral history or art.
6. They're not cannibals.

What else?

Comment: Hey, Robyn, this seems more like a question for [writing.se] than here, that being said you may well get some interesting/useful stuff before closure as off-topic. Not voting to close at present, will re-visit that decision in a few hours.

Comment: This has nothing to do with building your world and everything to do with how you present your story to your audience. Voting to close as _off-topic_. Cliches are not part of worldbuilding; they're part of writing. I agree with Confounded that you would probably receive better feedback on the Writing SE.

Comment: Why not? Any story is gonna go throught clichés.. Here you are creating your own nomadic people, so whatever is the situation you will fit them in. That's the main point of worldbuilding. Also, racism or cannibalism or any of this concept have a place in writing, because they are part of the human behavior, and whatever you are doing (writing, RPG, etc...) your main target is humans who will indentify or reject some of this concepts. Getting subjects to avoid seems to be the opposite of what worldbuilding is for : liberty, imagination.

Comment: I considered posting it to Writing, but I am looking for characteristics of the nomadic society, not characteristics of the hero, which is why I posted it here. Can questions be moved between forums, or would I have to post it again?

Comment: @Robyn You'll need to post it again, you can copy and paste which will save you a lot of hassles, I'd suggest the Tags Conventions and Tropes over on the Writing.SE, I'm not sure how well received it will be there but it is a better fit than here.

Comment: @Robyn I'd say it's not so much about *avoiding* cliches as figuring out how to *transform* them into something valuable to the story: vis-a-vis - cannibalism, Christianity transformed this into the Eucharist, one of the sacred sacraments. Cliches are cliches for a reason, because they represent basic human tendencies, and thus tend to turn up quite a bit in relation to human behaviour.  Best of luck.

Comment: Nuffin wrong with tipis (or lavvus, or yurts, or tupiqs or whatever else). Portable shelters tend to converge on a fair comment set of design elements that'll be hard to avoid. They'll almost certainly want to sleep under _something_, unless they're unusually hardcore or live somewhere with an unusually benign climate.

Comment: I don't see how this is not worldbuilding - *maybe* "too broad" since it can't have a single acceptable answer but surely looking for help building a society is about worldbuilding!

Comment: @Colmde, it's asking for a list

Comment: @StarfishPrime indeed it makes perfect sense to live in a tent. And equally there are many good reasons why someone would choose to make religious art out of a log. As I understand it, the difficulty with having teepees and totem poles at the same time is it usually means you have a grab-bag of Native American images but haven't focused on any particular Native American group. However this is not my area of expertise, I could be wrong.